# ComfortMaker GUH075 series high-efficiency (93%) furnace isn't making heat

Tags: furnace

It worked a couple of days ago but today the fan blows but the burner doesn't seem to come on.  The status indicator inside the access panel flashes four times but I can't find any reference to tell me what that means.

Comment: Is it the blower fan running, or the draft inducer? Do you have the owner's manual? From the limited info I could find, 4 blinks could be an open high limit. This would be consistent with the blower continuously running with no flame.

Comment: Definitely the blower. The is cool coming out of the vents. I have the "User's Information Manual"  which seems to have no useful information.

Comment: After having it off for ~30 hours it is working again. For now. Burner is lit and there is warm air coming out the vents.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty air filter will cause that fault... not enough air flow through the heat exchanger resulting in "open high limit".
 (Embarrassed to say , I let that happen last winter).